# How to invalidate StackExchange sessions

Tags: support, login

I have changed my StackExchange OpenID password, but I noticed that my login sessions on the websites of the network (StackOverflow, ServerFault, etc) are still valid.

Of course I've used a different browser to ensure that cookies were not shared or updated.

How do I terminate all sessions or forcefully logout other machines?

I need to ensure that my session terminates on another computer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210002/log-out-button-illogical-placement

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it does not work. The other browser is still logged in.

Comment: Interesting.  Did you just log out from one browser or both?  Did you log out of both at the same time?

Comment: No, only with one. I want to make sure that I can "kick out" the other browser/device, and invalidate its session.

Comment: Moderators do have a per-site option to clear all sessions for a particular user, but I think a good feature request would be to automatically trigger a process like that across all sites, or at least a checkbox that allows a user to trigger it. First, though, they should [implement this feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232256/can-the-change-password-dialog-please-ask-for-my-current-password). I can clear your sessions on Stack Overflow if you wish. :)

Comment: Thank you @animuson, that would be great... especially now that you've pointed out that you don't need to type your old password to change it. This, together with the fact that you can't forcefully log out other clients, is kind of worrying.

Comment: So, yes, I would like to be logged out from everything, please. I will re-login later only on some devices.

Comment: I've cleared your sessions on Stack Overflow. It should force you to login again there. Unfortunately, that is the only site where I have the power to do that.

Comment: Thank you @animuson. I did notice yesterday that I had been logged out  from all browsers. However...

Comment: I just opened SO, switched to another browser tab for a few seconds and, when I came back, the familiar message (horizontal bar at the top of the screen) told me that I had been recognized and automatically logged in.

Comment: I wrote to the user support of StackExchange. Let's see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you can only be logged into openid.stackexchange.com on one machine/browser/etc at a time; simply logging in will invalidate your sessions elsewhere.

Universal Auth allows you to log out from all sites and all devices in one go.

1. Open the Hamburger menu
2. Click the log out link
3. Check Log out on all devices
4. Click the Log Out button

Prior to Universal Auth you had to follow these steps:

With that out of the way, I'm afraid there's no *easy* way to make sure you're logged out of all sites on all machines. You're stuck with the following process:

1. Log into every site that you *might've* logged into on a different machine.
2. Log out of each site that you just logged into.
3. Wait 5-10 minutes.

Just to be safe, I went ahead and cleared your outstanding sessions; this answer is for future reference.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the limit of 1 concurrent session for openid.stackexchange.com -- however, I did click `logout`, and yet I was re-logged-in automatically. Even now, that you have cleared my sessions, I still logged in automatically.

Comment: That... shouldn't be happening, @tom. Would you mind logging out with your browser's error console open, and seeing if there are any errors logged?

Comment: Ok. I can confirm that it just happened again with [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/): I opened the page and was not logged in. After a few seconds, a message bar told me that I had been recognized, and asked me to reload. After that, I was logged in.

Comment: Anyway, the situation because of which I decided to reset my browser sessions has been resolved, so it's not urgent anymore.

Comment: But this __is__ interesting, so let's get to the bottom of it. Logging out now, looking at the browser JS console.

Comment: Ok. Done. I didn't notice any message in the console. This time, however, worked as expected: visiting SO again did __not__ log me back in.